# UPDATED: Using JS to make sure Firefox reloads (F5) first slide of slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am using .localScroll buttons (#slideshow-nav), anchored to two sets of lists- images (#slideshow) and text (#slideshow-text) & then added .hide and .slideDown effects to the text.  So each button clicked causes it's linked image and it's hidden text to scroll into position, and then the text appears.  It works in all browsers but Firefox, which, when I refresh the browser, the button and the text return to the first listed position, but the image does not.  Is there a JS solution that anyone could suggest?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.localscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {   
      $("#slideshow, #slideshow-text").css("overflow", "hidden");
      $("#slideshow-nav").css("visibility", "visible");     
      $("#slideshow-nav li:first-child a").addClass("active");

      $.localScroll({target:'#slideshow', axis: 'x'
   });

   $("#slideshow-nav a").click(function(){ 
      $("#slideshow-nav a").removeClass("active");
      $("#slideshow-text li").hide();                           

      var childIdx = parseInt($($(this)[0].parentElement).index(), 10) + 1
         $("#slideshow-text li:nth-child(" +  childIdx + ")").hide("slow", function() {
            $("#slideshow-text li:nth-child(" +  childIdx +        ")").slideDown("slow");                                                                             
         });
      $(this).addClass("active");
   });
});`
</script>
```

Comment: I asked a JS expert that I know and he was stumped.  Apparently, the lack of response here also indicates this is a puzzler.  Bummer... oh well.